# SQL SERVER Select MAX Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to make a procedure that changes the user login on a table,but change only the last entry if its in a specific status:Here is the procudure i'm trying:

```
Update T_STATUS_CLIC 
SET iEDV = @iEDV 
WHERE 
    iClic = @iClic and iStatus = '9' and dtDateCreated = 
    (select max (dtDateCreated)  FROM T_STATUS_CLIC where iclic = @iClic );
```

I can only change the iEDV if the last row of the table the max date,is in the iStatus 9,i dont know if this is possible,i'm trying something like this:

```
iStatus = (select iStatus = '9' where max(dtDateCreated))
```

But didn't work,is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can use TOP (1) and Order by in Update too. ;-) Just try this.

Comment: your first query seems to be valid. are you sure there are records that meets this criteria?

Comment: Something like this?             Update top 1 T_STATUS_CLIC SET iEDV = iEDV WHERE iClic = iClic and iStatus = '9' order by dtDateCreated;

Comment: If there is a newer `dtDateCreated` with an `iStatus <> 9` then the record won't get updated.  If you want to update the record with max date and `istatus = 9` just include `AND iStatus = '9'` in your '(select max()` query

Comment: The select max query is return error in the AND  (Incorrect syntax)                 dtDateCreated = (select max (dtDateCreated and iStatus = '9')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you can have many rows per "iClic" and only want to update the row if the most recent has a status = 9.

It would help if the table had a true PK.

But I believe this will work, given:

```
CREATE TABLE T_STATUS_CLIC (iClic INT , iEDV INT, iStatus CHAR(1), dtDateCreated DateTime)
DECLARE @iEDV int = 123;
DECLARE @iClic int = 8888;
```

this script:

```
; -- WITH must be preceeded by a semicolon
WITH clicmax as (SELECT iClic
                ,   max(dtDateCreated) as maxdt 
                ,   max(case when mc.iStatus = '9' THEN mc.dtDateCreated ELSE null END) as Max9dt
                FROM dbo.T_STATUS_CLIC mc WHERE iClic = @iClic GROUP BY iClic)
UPDATE tt
SET iEDV = @iEDV
FROM dbo.T_STATUS_CLIC tt
    JOIN clicmax on clicmax.iClic = tt.iClic 
WHERE tt.iClic = @iClic
and tt.dtDateCreated = clicmax.Max9dt  
and tt.dtDateCreated = clicmax.Maxdt
and tt.iStatus = '9';
```

The WITH clause determines BOTH the actual max date and the max date for status 9.  The update can then reference both of these in its WHERE clause.